# Exoplayer v2.9 TransferListener does not take parameters

Tags: java, android, exoplayer2.x

I've just updated my exoplayer from 2.8.4 to v2.9.
But now, I've got the following error :
error: type TransferListener does not take parameters

Error seems refer to this line :

> ```
>     mediaDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "mediaPlayerSample"), (TransferListener<? super DataSource>) bandwidthMeter);
> ```

More specialy to TransferListener.

Here the complete method (worked on 2.8.4) :

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);

    shouldAutoPlay = true;
    bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    mediaDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "mediaPlayerSample"), (TransferListener<? super DataSource>) bandwidthMeter);

    window = new Timeline.Window();
    ivHideControllerButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.exo_controller);

}
```

Anybody can tell me what's the problem since update ?

Thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 mediaDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "mediaPlayerSample"), (TransferListener) bandwidthMeter);
```

And add these line to `build.gradle`

```
android {
...
...
   compileOptions {
         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
...
}
```

Remember to use latest `gradle-5.1.1-all`